# Android Foursquare how to get the token

Tags: java, android

I have an app that connects to my Foursquare account. The authentication is successful, but when it comes to showing my username (it shows null) and the list of venues around me, I can't get through it.

What should be done?

Main.java

```
public class Main extends Activity {
     private FoursquareApp mFsqApp;
     private ListView mListView;
     private NearbyAdapter mAdapter;
     private ArrayList<FsqVenue> mNearbyList;
     private ProgressDialog mProgress;

     public static final String CLIENT_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
     public static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     setContentView(R.layout.main);

     final TextView nameTv      = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
     Button connectBtn          = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_connect);
     final EditText latitudeEt  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_latitude);
     final EditText longitudeEt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_longitude);
     Button goBtn               = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_go);
     mListView                  = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_places);

     mFsqApp        = new FoursquareApp(this, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);

     mAdapter       = new NearbyAdapter(this);
     mNearbyList        = new ArrayList<FsqVenue>();
     mProgress      = new ProgressDialog(this);

     mProgress.setMessage("Loading data ...");


     if (mFsqApp.hasAccessToken()) nameTv.setText("Connected as " + mFsqApp.getUserName());

     FsqAuthListener listener = new FsqAuthListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Connected as " +   mFsqApp.getUserName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            nameTv.setText("Connected as " + mFsqApp.getUserName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFail(String error) {
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

      mFsqApp.setListener(listener);

    //get access token and user name from foursquare
      connectBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mFsqApp.authorize();
        }
    });  

    //use access token to get nearby places
    goBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String latitude  = latitudeEt.getText().toString();
            String longitude = longitudeEt.getText().toString();

            if (latitude.equals("") || longitude.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Latitude or longitude is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            double lat  = Double.valueOf(latitude);
            double lon  = Double.valueOf(longitude);

            loadNearbyPlaces(lat, lon);
        }
    });
}

private void loadNearbyPlaces(final double latitude, final double longitude) {
    mProgress.show();

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int what = 0;

            try {

                mNearbyList = mFsqApp.getNearby(latitude, longitude);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                what = 1;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(what));
        }
    }.start();
}

private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        mProgress.dismiss();

        if (msg.what == 0) {
            if (mNearbyList.size() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(Main.this, "No nearby places available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            mAdapter.setData(mNearbyList);              
            mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Failed to load nearby places", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
};
    }
```

FoursquareApp.java

```
    public class FoursquareApp {
private FoursquareSession mSession;
private FoursquareDialog mDialog;
private FsqAuthListener mListener;
private ProgressDialog mProgress;
private String mTokenUrl;
private String mAccessToken;


public static final String CALLBACK_URL = "https://www.foursquare.com";
private static final String AUTH_URL = "https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate";
private static final String TOKEN_URL = "https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token";
private static final String API_URL = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2";

private static final String TAG = "FoursquareApi";

public FoursquareApp(Context context, String clientId, String clientSecret) {
    mSession        = new FoursquareSession(context);

    mAccessToken    = mSession.getAccessToken();

    mTokenUrl       = TOKEN_URL + "?client_id=" + clientId + "&client_secret=" + clientSecret + "&grant_type=authorization_code"
                    + "&redirect_uri=" + CALLBACK_URL;

    String url      = AUTH_URL + "?client_id=" + clientId + "&response_type=code" + "&redirect_uri=" + CALLBACK_URL;

    FsqDialogListener listener = new FsqDialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String code) {
            getAccessToken(code);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String error) {
            mListener.onFail("Authorization failed");
        }
    };

    mDialog         = new FoursquareDialog(context, url, listener);
    mProgress       = new ProgressDialog(context);

    mProgress.setCancelable(false);
}

private void getAccessToken(final String code) {
    mProgress.setMessage("Getting access token ...");
    mProgress.show();

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "Getting access token");

            int what = 0;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(mTokenUrl + "&code=" + code);

                Log.i(TAG, "Opening URL " + url.toString());

                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                //urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                urlConnection.connect();

                JSONObject jsonObj  = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(streamToString(urlConnection.getInputStream())).nextValue();
                mAccessToken        = jsonObj.getString("access_token");


            } catch (Exception ex) {
                what = 1;

                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(what, 1, 0));
        }
    }.start();
}

private void fetchUserName() {
    mProgress.setMessage("Finalizing ...");

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "Fetching user name");
            int what = 0;

            try {
                String v    = timeMilisToString(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
                URL url     = new URL(API_URL + "/users/self?oauth_token=" + mAccessToken + "&v=" + v);

                Log.d(TAG, "Opening URL " + url.toString());

                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                urlConnection.connect();

                String response     = streamToString(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                JSONObject jsonObj  = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();

                JSONObject resp     = (JSONObject) jsonObj.get("response");
                JSONObject user     = (JSONObject) resp.get("user");

                String firstName    = user.getString("firstName");
                String lastName     = user.getString("lastName");

                Log.i(TAG, "Got user name: " + firstName + " " + lastName);

                mSession.storeAccessToken(mAccessToken, firstName + " " + lastName);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                what = 1;

                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(what, 2, 0));
        }
    }.start();
}

private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg.arg1 == 1) {
            if (msg.what == 0) {
                fetchUserName();
            } else {
                mProgress.dismiss();

                mListener.onFail("Failed to get access token");
            }
        } else {
            mProgress.dismiss();

            mListener.onSuccess();
        }
    }
};

public boolean hasAccessToken() {
    return (mAccessToken == null) ? false : true;
}

public void setListener(FsqAuthListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return mSession.getUsername();
}

public void authorize() {
    mDialog.show();
}

public ArrayList<FsqVenue> getNearby(double latitude, double longitude) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<FsqVenue> venueList = new ArrayList<FsqVenue>();

    try {
        String v    = timeMilisToString(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
        String ll   = String.valueOf(latitude) + "," + String.valueOf(longitude);
        URL url     = new URL(API_URL + "/venues/search?ll=" + ll + "&oauth_token=" + mAccessToken + "&v=" + v);

        Log.d(TAG, "Opening URL " + url.toString());

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        //urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        urlConnection.connect();

        String response     = streamToString(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        JSONObject jsonObj  = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();

        JSONArray groups    = (JSONArray) jsonObj.getJSONObject("response").getJSONArray("groups");

        int length          = groups.length();

        if (length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                JSONObject group    = (JSONObject) groups.get(i);
                JSONArray items     = (JSONArray) group.getJSONArray("items");

                int ilength         = items.length();

                for (int j = 0; j < ilength; j++) {
                    JSONObject item = (JSONObject) items.get(j);

                    FsqVenue venue  = new FsqVenue();

                    venue.id        = item.getString("id");
                    venue.name      = item.getString("name");

                    JSONObject location = (JSONObject) item.getJSONObject("location");

                    Location loc    = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                    loc.setLatitude(Double.valueOf(location.getString("lat")));
                    loc.setLongitude(Double.valueOf(location.getString("lng")));

                    venue.location  = loc;
                    venue.address   = location.getString("address");
                    venue.distance  = location.getInt("distance");
                    venue.herenow   = item.getJSONObject("hereNow").getInt("count");
                    venue.type      = group.getString("type");

                    venueList.add(venue);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    }

    return venueList;
}

private String streamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    String str  = "";

    if (is != null) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        try {
            BufferedReader reader   = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            reader.close();
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }

        str = sb.toString();
    }

    return str;
}

private String timeMilisToString(long milis) {
    SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    Calendar calendar   = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.setTimeInMillis(milis);

    return sd.format(calendar.getTime());
}
public interface FsqAuthListener {
    public abstract void onSuccess();
    public abstract void onFail(String error);
}
    }
```

FsqVenue.java

```
    public class FsqVenue {
public String id;
public String name;
public String address;
public String type;
public Location location;
public int direction;
public int distance;
public int herenow;
    }
```

FoursquareDialog.java

```
    public class FoursquareDialog extends Dialog {
static final float[] DIMENSIONS_LANDSCAPE = {460, 260};
static final float[] DIMENSIONS_PORTRAIT = {280, 420};
static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams FILL = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
static final int MARGIN = 4;
static final int PADDING = 2;

private String mUrl;
private FsqDialogListener mListener;
private ProgressDialog mSpinner;
private WebView mWebView;
private LinearLayout mContent;
private TextView mTitle;

private static final String TAG = "Foursquare-WebView";

public FoursquareDialog(Context context, String url, FsqDialogListener listener) {
    super(context);

    mUrl        = url;
    mListener   = listener;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mSpinner = new ProgressDialog(getContext());

    mSpinner.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mSpinner.setMessage("Loading...");

    mContent = new LinearLayout(getContext());

    mContent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    setUpTitle();
    setUpWebView();

    Display display     = getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    final float scale   = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    float[] dimensions  = (display.getWidth() < display.getHeight()) ? DIMENSIONS_PORTRAIT : DIMENSIONS_LANDSCAPE;

    addContentView(mContent, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams((int) (dimensions[0] * scale + 0.5f),
                                (int) (dimensions[1] * scale + 0.5f)));

    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getContext()); 

    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

    cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
}

 private void setUpTitle() {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        Drawable icon = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.foursquare_icon);

        mTitle = new TextView(getContext());

        mTitle.setText("Foursquare");
        mTitle.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        mTitle.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        mTitle.setBackgroundColor(0xFF0cbadf);
        mTitle.setPadding(MARGIN + PADDING, MARGIN, MARGIN, MARGIN);
        mTitle.setCompoundDrawablePadding(MARGIN + PADDING);
        mTitle.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(icon, null, null, null);

        mContent.addView(mTitle);
    }

    private void setUpWebView() {
        mWebView = new WebView(getContext());

        mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new TwitterWebViewClient());
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl(mUrl);
        mWebView.setLayoutParams(FILL);

        mContent.addView(mWebView);
    }

    private class TwitterWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Redirecting URL " + url);

            if (url.startsWith(FoursquareApp.CALLBACK_URL)) {
                String urls[] = url.split("=");

                mListener.onComplete(urls[1]);

                FoursquareDialog.this.dismiss();

                return true;                    
            } 

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Page error: " + description);

            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);

            mListener.onError(description);

            FoursquareDialog.this.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Loading URL: " + url);
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            mSpinner.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            String title = mWebView.getTitle();
            if (title != null && title.length() > 0) {
                mTitle.setText(title);
            }
            mSpinner.dismiss();
        }

    }

public interface FsqDialogListener {
    public abstract void onComplete(String accessToken);
    public abstract void onError(String error);
}
    }
```

FoursquareSession.java

```
    public class FoursquareSession {
private SharedPreferences sharedPref;
private Editor editor;

private static final String SHARED = "Foursquare_Preferences";
private static final String FSQ_USERNAME = "username";
private static final String FSQ_ACCESS_TOKEN = "access_token";

public FoursquareSession(Context context) {
    sharedPref    = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    editor        = sharedPref.edit();
}

public void storeAccessToken(String accessToken, String username) {
    editor.putString(FSQ_ACCESS_TOKEN, accessToken);
    editor.putString(FSQ_USERNAME, username);

    editor.commit();
}

public void resetAccessToken() {
    editor.putString(FSQ_ACCESS_TOKEN, null);
    editor.putString(FSQ_USERNAME, null);

    editor.commit();
}


public String getUsername() {
    return sharedPref.getString(FSQ_USERNAME, null);
}

public String getAccessToken() {
    return sharedPref.getString(FSQ_ACCESS_TOKEN, null);
}
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.londatiga.fsq"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".Main" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   </application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses- permission>

    </manifest>
```

[image]